# How does Politics SE define a decade / century / millennium? '0-'9 or '1-'0?

Tags: discussion

I have seen a lot of questions involving a *"decade"*:

> - [How did the US approval ratings in the Middle East change over the last two decades?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9493/25526)
> - [Did the Greek economy contract more than Syria's in the past decade?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/33094/25526)
> - [How many new settlements did Israel build in the last decade in the West Bank?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8698/25526)

How does Politics SE here define a fixed time period of a decade/century/millennium?

Some users and I have been in a conversation on [this question:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339225)

> - **Me:** 2021 is a different **decade!** (Current decade: 2011-2020, next decade: 2021-2030)
> - **User45266:** Most people define a decade as starting with the year ending in a zero: The Sixties started in 1960 (duh), and therefore 1970 was part of the Seventies, not the Sixties. The (20)'20s will include the year 2020.
> - **JJ:** well, I'd invite "most people" to [take a look here.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11284/71848) On English (the site), **many regard the year ending with zero as the end of a decade / century / millennium.** It's quite interesting.
> - **User45266:** Whoa! I can feel my horizons broadening! I never knew that that was even up for debate. Although with decades, **I've never heard anyone argue that 1990 was part of the '80s.** *It's probably the same thing as saying "the 1900's" versus "the 20th century".* I bet this is going to blow up in the media with people taking both sides once New Year's Eve rolls around... you heard it here first :)
> - **JJ:** Well I wouldn't recommend posting a happy new decade post on the ELU Meta site at the end of this year. :p
> - **M69:** *Actually this was a big thing when **billions** of idiots celebrated the start of the new millennium in the year 2000.*
> - **User45266:** But would they have been wrong in celebrating the start of the 2000s? I have a hard time believing that the year 2000 was part of the 1900s, but I could maybe see it being part of the 20th century... *Ultimately, does it even matter?*
> - **BSMP:** *0 = **10** not 1.* If you asked someone to organize a bunch of sticks in bundles of 10, would you expect them to put the 10th stick in the 2nd bundle? The first bundle would only have 9 sticks. ***A group of 10 includes the 10th thing.*** *(For 0 to be 1 there’d have to be a year 0 and there isn’t.)*

BSMP and some other users tried to correct User45266.  But instead of accepting the truth and moving on, User45266 would only decline and escalate from there.

> - **User45266:** Okay, but take those same ten sticks (actually, let's make it a hundred - you'll see why), label them *0-99* and spread them out on a table. Now, if I asked you to take all the "forties" out, ***would you grab stick number fifty** (and leave out stick forty)?* To me, that's ridiculous.
> - **User45266:** Now, we do have words like "century" and "decade" that are specifically tied to the chronological system we use, and to me it's fine to define a "decade", "century", or "millenium" as "one-indexed" (first ordinal number is one) rather than "zero-indexed", *since our calendar system excludes a year zero.* But to take a word like "the **two** thousands" and include "***three*** (!) thousand" is illogical; it goes against the very meaning of the number two thousand.

And now, he/she reaches into a massive climax where I would have completely **fainted.**

> - **User45266:** *To take this to an extreme, what if the number of things in a group is only one? Example: Is the year 2179 part of the "two thousands"? Of course. Is the year 2179 part of the "twenty-one hundreds"? Yup. Is the year 2179 part of the "seventies" (2170s)? Duh. But is the year 2179 part of the "nines"? I think it clearly should be! You can't possibly argue that it's part of the "eights", can you?*
> - **User45266:** *If you want to argue that the year 2179 will actually be the 2,178th "monoyear" (?) or something, be my guest, but you can't tell me that 2179 will be a part of the 2178th year.*

Does Politics SE here define a "fixed" decade / century / millennium as '1-'0 or '0-'9?  I would argue to follow the '1-'0 method.  This is a more accurate method, since the first year was marked as year *I*, not *nulla*. (*I* and *nulla* = 1 and 0)  In this view, the 0s (the first decade) ran from year 1-10.  Note that the year **10** is **not** part of the 10**'s**.  In this view, the current year is 2020 and is part of the 2010s (2011-2020).  *"Most people"* (?) would define the current decade (2020s) as 2020-2029 and not 2021-2030, according to what User45266 had said.  So does Politics SE generally define the *"last decade"* as 2001-2010 or 2010-2019?

---

In general, does this site define a decade/century/millennium as '1-'0/'01-'00/'001-'000 or as '0-'9/'00-'99/'000-'999?

This is how **I** define the current peroid:

- Year: 2020
- Decade: 2010s (2011-2020)
- Century: 21st century (2001-2100)
- Millennium: 3rd millennium (2001-3000)

Comment: 2020.0 to 2030.0 - Boundaries are at midnight local time so Jan 1st 2030 at 12:00:01 AM is a new decade.

Comment: [We base our decades on the authority of VH-1](https://xkcd.com/2249/)

Comment: @SurpriseDog Jan 1st 203**1**, not 2030.  You are saying it is 2020-2029.  0 is 10 not 1.  For 0 to be 1 there should be a "year 0" and there was no "year 0".  The first year was in fact year **1** and not 0.  BSMP is correct.

Comment: @Machavity Ok, it seems like a moderator should come here and tell the truth.

Comment: @Yubin-chan Well the denizens of year 1 are free to complain about their decade being short changed, lol.

Comment: Obviously, I'm biased, but I think the key quote in the comment discussion you referenced is **"Ultimately, does it even matter?"**

Comment: @user45266 yes.

Comment: @user45266 0 is 10, not 1.  The first "decade" (?) is marked as **0's**, but there is no "year 0".  We usually start counting from **1** and not 0.  A decade is a period of 10 years.  So **0's** will include the years **1-10**.

Comment: How about centuries / millenniums?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think any distinction you make between the two would be hard pressed to find a notable difference, as such in questions where there is ambiguity (in other words where it actually makes a difference), I propose we either ask the questioner to specify, or answerers can make a determination as to which range they wish to use and provide a good answer.

This may lead to having multiple good answers on individual questions, but I for one would be pretty interested to see them both. Having both possibilities may provide insight on such questions which may not be available if only a single rule is strictly enforced.

Comment: I edited my question.  Please edit this answer accordingly, too.